C# JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower not working
I'm trying to convert a json string to an object and back again to a string, to change the json formatting. The reason why I'm doing this is a longer story and has something to do with gRPC repeated field.
Now heres a snippet that I would expect to convert the casing of the json string to snake casing:
using System.Text.Json;

string json = "{\"MyImportantParameter\":\"MyContent\"}";

var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(json);

JsonSerializerOptions opts = new() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower };
string json2 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj, opts);

I've already tried fiddling around with options, like deserializing with different options, but what ever I do, json and json2 are equal.
What am I doing wrong here?

PropertyNamingPolicy only effects the serialization of compile-time defined properties of some data model, but when you deserialize to object you are deserializing to the System.Text.Json DOM object JsonElement -- and PropertyNamingPolicy doesn't apply to that.  See the open issue [API Proposal]: JsonSerializerOptions.JsonObjectKeyPolicy (naming policy) #79624 for confirmation: It seems there is no way to let STJ handle naming convention mappings for any of the STJ DOM types.

If you don't want to design a data model, NamingPolicyJsonElementConverter from .NET 6 - Type Agnostic Json Serialization with camelCase through PropertyNamingPolicy works for your case also as long as you deserialize to JsonElement, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/wQmgwS.

This question is similar to: .NET 6 - Type Agnostic Json Serialization with camelCase through PropertyNamingPolicy. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you @dbc for pointing out

PropertyNamingPolicy only effects the serialization of compile-time
defined properties [...]

Now I came up with this as my solution:
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static string? NormalizeJsonString(string jsonString, JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions)
    {
        var jsonObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonObject>(jsonString);

        if (jsonObject != null)
        {
            ApplyPropertyNamingPolicy(jsonObject, jsonSerializerOptions);
        }

        var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonObject, jsonSerializerOptions);

        return result;
    }

    public static void ApplyPropertyNamingPolicy(JsonObject jsonObject, JsonSerializerOptions jsonSerializerOptions)
    {
        if (jsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy == null)
            return;

        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, JsonNode?>();
        foreach (var item in jsonObject)
        {
            var name = jsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy.ConvertName(item.Key);
            if (item.Value is JsonObject jsonSubObject)
            {
                ApplyPropertyNamingPolicy(jsonSubObject, jsonSerializerOptions);
            }
            else if (item.Value is JsonArray jsonArray)
            {
                foreach (var arrayItem in jsonArray)
                {
                    if (arrayItem is JsonObject arrayJsonObject)
                    {
                        ApplyPropertyNamingPolicy(arrayJsonObject, jsonSerializerOptions);
                    }
                }
            }
            dictionary[name] = item.Value;
        }

        jsonObject.Clear();

        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            jsonObject.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
}


I don't think this will work on 2d, 3d or n-d jagged arrays like [ [ {"MyImportantParameter":"MyContent"} ] ].  You would need to recurse on JsonNode rather than just on JsonObject to handle arrays of arbitrary dimension.
